# Обособление приложений в начале предложений

Tags: запятые, приложение

Дорогие участники сообщества, подскажите, пожалуйста, ведь здесь нужна же запятая?!

Как Технический директор (?) Вы создали безупречный механизм взаимодействия всех подразделений предприятия.

Здесь же ведь есть дополнительное значение причинности или *"будучи техническим директором..."*, поэтому выделяется запятой?..

Comment: СООБЩНИК, -а, м. Соучастник преступления (Ожегов), Сообщник м. Соучастник преступления, каких-либо неблаговидных дел. (Ефремова). СООБЩНИК, сообщника, ·муж. (офиц.). Соучастник преступного замысла или деяния (Ушаков). Внёс правку в вопрос.

Comment: Ой, извините.. А я видела, что другие здесь так начинали свои вопросы... Вот решила тоже повторить... А мне, оказывается, нельзя... Ну, ничего страшного...

Comment: Не надо комплексов) Я тут не 24/7. Где увидел, там и пояснил. Я же не каждый вопрос читаю.

Comment: Ну все, извините, больше никаких комплексов... Это хорошо, что вы сказали...

Comment: Что разрешили, вернее... А юмора или иронии в моем обращении Вы, конечно, не углядели...

Comment: Конечно, нет. Здесь вообще-то серьёзные люди сидят. Мы не приемлем ошибки конкретных пользователей и категорически не воспринимаем юмор. Шесть лет на сайте, а до сих пор не в курсе.

Comment: Юмор не воспринимаете, сами только шутите...  Спасибо, что отметили кол-во моего здесь времяпребывания... Вообщем, шутить здесь, понятно, нельзя... Раньше такого не было... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оборот со значением тождества следует обособить, так как он имеет **причинное** значение:  ***Как Технический дирЕктор,**  Вы создали безупречный механизм взаимодействия всех подразделений предприятия.*

Сравнить: ***Будучи техническим директором**, Вы создали безупречный механизм взаимодействия всех подразделений предприятия.*

Значение причины заключается в том, что у названного лица  в должности технического директора были для этого возможности и полномочия.

Структура предложения также способствует обособлению, так как в  этом случае  оборот вделен логическим ударением.

Розенталь  https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111
7. Обособленное приложение может присоединяться союзом как (с дополнительным значением причинности). Как старый артиллерист, я презираю этот вид холодного украшения (Ш.);

Comment: Холодного оружия ;) И директор почему с выделенной буквой Е?.. А так - спасибо большое за ответ, это как раз та аргументация, которую я хотела получить...

Answer (score 2):

Я бы поставил запятую.

Одна из функций запятой - выделение дополнительных частей предложения (частей, которые могут быть убраны без потери главной мысли). Под многими чёткими правилами подразумевается именно она.

Даже если бы имелось в виду сравнение "вы сделали механизм прямо как тот технический директор", а не "являясь директором", то всё равно поставил бы.